# Save 4 byte pP depth image from shared memory

Tags: c++, image, opencv, shared-memory

So far every time I had a question this community helped me without me having to ask a question, but today I have to ask my first question, because I couldn't find an answer and I am desperate for the communities help.

I am working with a simulation Program which writes images into shared memory. Accessing the memory address, I want to save the images. The simulation is sending two images, one normal an one with depth information. Saving the normal image with open cv is no problem.

Reading and saving the normal image is done as follows:

```
//find image in Memory
uchar *imageMem = (uchar*)img + sizeof( RDB_IMAGE_t );

//set heights and width to image parameters
int w = img->width;
int h = img->height;

//create matrix for image
Mat image(h,w,CV_8UC3,imageMem);

//image is upside-down in memory, so it has to be flipped
Mat flipped;
flip(image,flipped,0);

//change color from bgr to rgb
Mat recolored;
cvtColor(flipped, recolored, COLOR_BGR2RGB);

string folderName = "normal";
string name = "normal_";
string type = ".png";

ss << folderName << "/" << name << simFrame << type;

string filename = ss.str();
ss.str("");
imwrite( filename, recolored );
```

Now to the actual problem. The simulation saves the depth information under a different shared memory address, but always into img. Depending on the index of the image the normal or depth the pointer img points to the corresponding memory address. The address for the normal image is 0x0811a and for the depth image 0x0811b. The code for saving the depth image looks as follows:

```
uchar *imageMem = (uchar*)img + sizeof( RDB_IMAGE_t );

int w = img->width;
int h = img->height;

Mat image_d(h,w,CV_8UC4,imageMem);

Mat flipped;
flip(image_d,flipped,0);

Mat recolored;
cvtColor(flipped, recolored, CV_BGRA2GRAY, 1);

string folderName = "Depth";
string name = "Depth_";
string type = ".png";

ss << folderName << "/" << name << simFrame << type;

string filename = ss.str();
ss.str("");
imwrite( filename, recolored );
```

The result after saving the depth information looks like this:

[image: Depth image while using CV_8UC4 to save the image.]

But it should look like this:

[image: How the image should look like after saving.]

The developer of the simulation says the depth image is send to the shared memory as a 4 byte per pixel image and one pixel always has the value 255. This information doesn't help me, but maybe you.

All I know about image processing I thought my self and at this point I really don't know what to do.

[Image Micka requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF5U5.png)

Comment: what type is img? What is the value of sizeof( RDB_IMAGE_t );?

Comment: can you remove the cvtColor line and save the image as .png and upload it, please?

Comment: Title says "4 bit depth", text says "4 byte per pixel", so which one is it? Also can't you just inspect shared memory or dump it after each step to find out when corruption happened?

Comment: Hello guys. Thanks for getting back so fast. @ Micka: I provided more information about img in the text (just edited) and the size of RDB_IMAGE_t is 32. @VTT: the title is a typo its 4 byte per pixel. I think there is no earlier excess of the image. The image is saved under a certain memory address img points to the image and I write the image into an open cv matrix. And what you see then is shown the new image I added (but not flipped). THX

Answer (score 0):

If you split the image you have provided into its constituent channels, you will find a couple of things.

Firstly, it has 4 channels - let's assume for a minute that they are R, G, B and A (although they are not actually).

Secondly, the last two channels are identical - their min/max and standard deviation are the same so we can discard one of them.

```
Image: depth.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 800x600+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColorAlpha
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
    Alpha: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 480000
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 181.668 (0.712422)
      standard deviation: 82.4882 (0.323483)
      kurtosis: -0.888916
      skewness: -0.74329
      entropy: 0.734481
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 175.737 (0.689165)
      standard deviation: 84.9054 (0.332963)
      kurtosis: -1.09314
      skewness: -0.611227
      entropy: 0.741165
    Blue:
      min: 229 (0.898039)                       <--- HERE
      max: 255 (1)                              <--- HERE
      mean: 252.276 (0.989316)                  <--- HERE
      standard deviation: 5.81622 (0.0228087)   <--- HERE
      kurtosis: 7.14093
      skewness: -2.88764
      entropy: 0.595817
    Alpha:
      min: 229 (0.898039)                       <--- HERE
      max: 255 (1)                              <--- HERE
      mean: 252.276 (0.989316)                  <--- HERE
      standard deviation: 5.81622 (0.0228087)   <--- HERE
      kurtosis: 7.14093
      skewness: -2.88764
      entropy: 0.595817
```

If you then extract the 4 channels, you will get this (R first, then G, then B):

[image]
[image]
[image]

I think that as the last image (B channel) just has 4-5 bands that get successively lighter the further you go into the image, it is probably the high byte. The first image (R channel) is banded, so I guess that is a smooth gradient in-between the larger steps in the B channel, so I guess that is the middle byte, The second image is varying the most wildly, so that is probably the least significant byte. I have not done any tests, but I guess if you used a formula something like this, it might work out correct:

```
24-bit depth = (Blue<<16) | (Red<<8) | Green
```

By way of example, if you take that formula and apply it (using **ImageMagick**) at the command line, like this:

```
convert depth.png -fx "(((u.b*255)<<8)|(u.r*255))/65535" -auto-level  result.png
```

You get this result which appears, to me at least, to show a nice, smooth depth image.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mark. I actually found out the same about the Pixelvalues, resulting in those 3 images. I also tried some mathematical equations I found on the internet, but none worked. Could you explain your formula a little bit more in detail? Thank you very much for taking the time. Regards Marcel

Comment: If you look at the middle image, from the middle of the left side going into the image towards the car, there are three clear bands going from black to white. So if you start with black (as value 0) and then build up to white (as value 255), you can see that as you get to white, the bottom image increases by 1 level which is how binary numbers add together, so the bottom image is the MSB and the top image is the next most significant byte because as the second byte reaches 255, the top byte clicks over to the next level.

Comment: I have updated my answer - please take another look at the final part.